# Paypal EC does not give me feedback when clicking on "Pay now" button

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am integrating Paypal Express Checkout with my PHP website.
When the user clicks some button, I open Paypal website on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext, it opens a Paypal login page.
As soon as the user clicks on "Login" button, there is some text "processing..." to indicate the click was ok and he has to wait for Paypal answer.

Then a Paypal review page appears and when the user clicks on "Pay now", nothing happens. The returnURL is executing but on the Paypal interface, nothing changes, and the user can click again and again.
In my case, the returnURL processes during 10 seconds, and the user doesn't know what is going on until the returnURL script has finished and redirects to my website.

I tried to put the header() on the first line of my returnURL instead of the last line, but it still redirect after the same delay.

There is a very little "waiting for sandbox..." and then "loading from mywebsite.com..." at the bottom of the window, but most users won't see it and it does not prevent them from clicking again and again on the "pay now" button.

**Edit** : If I redirect to Paypal page on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout, (instead of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext) when I click on "pay now", the page is blured with a "loading..." message. Here is the behaviour I expected. But I would prefer the popup page over the big Paypal page...

Comment: Do you have a (Sandbox) link we can take a look at? I'm not quite sure what's happening here and would like to see it myself. Thanks!

Comment: No I develop on MAMP, I can't show you...
The thing is when the client clicks on "Pay now" button on the Paypal Express Checkout shopping cart review, nothing happens immediately so the user can see his click on the button worked.
I wonder if everybody see the same behaviour or if it is related to my way of doing.

Answer (score 0):

As odd as it sounds, theres sometimes some weird interface issues that can occur when you log into live accounts, then multiple sandbox accounts, etc etc. It causes the cookie to get quite large and act strange. Can you try clearing your cache/cookies and see if your getting the same odd interface issues?

Comment: I cleared the cookies this morning and I have seen this behaviour all day. I don't think it is related to cookies, it seems to me the Paypal interface just does not react to the click on "Pay now" button, except calling the returnURL.